# Color coding for HackLang PHP Code in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, hacklang

When I write code in Netbeans PHP Project that begins with `<?hh` then the editor removes all the color coding.

For example, the file is called `index.php` and the color coding works great when the code is like this:

```
<?php

echo "hello world";
```

[image]

but the color coding disappears when I start with the HackLang `<?hh` tag like so:

```
<?hh

echo "hello world";
```

[image]

I tried finding some configuration in Netbeans so that it treats any file with a `.php` extension as PHP code no matter if I use `<?hh` or `<?php` in the start of it.

Does anyone know how to enable color coding in Netbeans irrespective of if I use `<?hh` or `<?php` at the beginning of the file?

Comment: [Seemingly not](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic59945.html), as of 11 months ago. As a last resort you could probably fix this in the source code, but you'd need to recompile the whole thing.

Comment: This might help, in case you want to hack NetBeans for support: https://github.com/hhvm/vim-hack/blob/master/after/syntax/php.vim